# Cannot Find ~/.profile, Only ~/.profile.swp (OSX)

Tags: macos, homebrew, swap, .profile

I am in the process of [installing Homebrew](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/), but, when I go to edit `~/.profile`, I am finding that only the binary file `~/.profile.swp` exists. I have been reading about swap files and trying to better understand their use, but have thus far only read about them in the context of backing up files that are open in vi or such, and so I'm not sure how I could have ended up with a swap of this one, which I have never opened. Am I looking in the wrong place for this file? It seems that where there exists a swap, there must exist an original.

I'm not very experienced with these systems, so please forgive the simplicity of my question.

System info: I'm on OSX 10.11 (El Capitan). The one odd thing about my setup is that I had an SSD installed in addition to my original drive at a local IT shop, and I don't know what the installer changed inside the machine to unify everything.

Comment: You might get a better response to this on our dedicated Apple site: [apple.se].

Comment: I don't think OS X, homebrew and your SSD have anything to do with this. Do you use vim? If so I guess this is a UNIX question.